# Linqpad to EXCEL File - CRUD

Tags: excel, linqpad

How can I do CRUD operation to XLS and/or XLSX file using linqpad ?

any help / pointers appreciated .

Comment: available option linq to excel doesnt work it says "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" eventhough the drivers are installed

Comment: If you have the 64-bit drivers installed, you could try the 64-bit build of LinqPad.

Comment: @sgmoore have installed fresh 64bit drivers going take a 64bit build now..